# Please review my workout plan using gymnastic rings

Tags: workout-routines, workout

I have a simple bodyweight gym at home which includes:

- pull up bar
- gymnastic rings on bar
- a 40lb brick

My workout plan is 3X a week, around 45m-1h:

1. Pullups 8 reps, 3set. Alternate with dip, 90s rest
2. Ring Dips 8 reps, 3sets. Alternate with pullup, 90s rest
3. Half-Pistol squats(too weak for a full pistol...), one leg at a time. Alternate with ring pushups. 90s rest
4. Ring pushups, 8 rep, 3 set, alternate with squats
5. Deadlift the brick 8 rep, 3 set... it's working right now since my legs are my weakness
6. Ring rows. 8 rep, 3 set. alternate with deadlift

Currently, I am only aiming for 8rep, but on the later sets I'm not able to push that far.

I think the upper body exercises I have are great and there are some methods to increment load for them, or I can wear weights.

My problem is on the lower body. Right now what I'm doing now is pretty taxing to me, so it's no problem. In fact, **I always struggle to catch my breath** after doing the leg exercises. I'm open to suggestions to a better way to approach them.

One of my struggles with this routine is even after a few months of being very good at the the exercises, I still struggle to meet all the reps. There's definitely significant gains, but for the last few exercises I can definitely feel the fatigue built up from previous exercises.

Overall, how would you rate this workout plan? What are some easy things I can add to make it more effective?

Answer (score 1):

> There's definitely significant gains, but for the last few exercises I can definitely feel the fatigue built up from previous exercise

If it works, it is fine. 10/10.

Just rember that when it gets to easy add more repetitions or more weight. If you can manage to increase by 1 repetition every week or every two weeks, then it will be perfect.

Alternatively you can progress in many other ways, like decreasing rest times or using explosive repetitions.